# Quando ou como integrar um código php em html

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação simples sem nenhum Framwork pra por em prática alguns conceitos que aprendi.

Estudei bastante sobre back-end com ênfase em POO, mas quando fui pro `index.php` surgiu as perguntas:

- E agora?
- Será que é assim mesmo?
- Será que tem que resumir essa parte?

**Pergunta 1:**

Eu li em alguns lugares que o certo é gerar os valores em `Json` para facilitar a manutenibilidade, mas sinceramente nunca entendi muito bem. Sei que devo fazer em `Json`, faço sempre que possível mas pra mim o `Json` é só um monte de chaves que enviamos para alguém. Pode me dar um exemplo em que as pessoas convertem o `Json` em `HTML`?

**Pergunta 2:**

A forma que eu to fazendo é a seguinte:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <?php
            require_once("autoload.php");
            $r = new objeto();
            $r->GerarNome("zezinho");
        ?>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1> <?php $r;//mostra "zezinho" ?> </H1>
    </BODY>
<HTML/>
```

Estou carregando as requires e criando objetos no head (No meu caso são só dados como nomes que vão ter na minha aplicação). Os resultado estão vindo mas eu sinto como se estivesse completamente errado, aquela sensação de não estar fazendo do jeito certo.
Eu queria saber se estou fazendo bem, se estou completamente errado, se tem que fazer de outra forma.

Se tiver uma forma nova, ou algo que recomendem a eu estudar, pode falar que quero fazer tudo possível para uma boa prática!

Comment: A ideia é separar as responsabilidades  (o que acontece no back e no front), assim mudanças em um não afetam diretamente o outro, geralmente o front é feito com algum framework como vue, angular ou react

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não está errado e nem certo. Há casos e casos.

Eu particularmente não gosto de utilizar PHP para renderizar HTML. Em meus cenários reais isso me dificultou a manutenção e eu perdi um pouco em performance. Mas, como eu disse, há casos e casos. Vamos lá.

### Cenário sem JSON (o seu):

O PHP está sendo executando conforme o DOM é renderizado no browser. Isto significa que o seu usuário só verá a página após o seu código ser processado.

**Prós**:

- o desenvolvimento fica mais simples e rápido, se utilizados os
  padrões corretos.

**Contras**:

- dependendo do que seu código faz, pode gerar lentidão.
- Dificuldade na manutenção, já que o seu código de front-end e back-end estarão misturados. (Por exemplo: suponha que você resolva fazer uma mudança de visual completa na aplicação. Você terá que lidar com o código html e ter cuidado para não quebrar o back-end da aplicação, já que este estará misturado)

### Cenário com JSON (API Rest):

Neste caso, o PHP será responsável por processar as requisições e entregar a resposta em forma de JSON para que você possa de maneira assíncrona (AJAX) capturá-las no front-end. Isto significa que o carregamento do DOM e a requisição HTTP serão feitas de maneira separadas.

**Prós:**

- Aplicações web mais vivas
- Facilidade na manutenção, já que os códigos estarão separados.
- Facilidade de implementar novas aplicações utilizando o mesmo backend. (Por exemplo: você tem um site e precisa levantar a versão mobile desse site. Você já terá o backend quase pronto, só precisará se preocupar com o front-end)

**Contras:**

- O desenvolvimento pode ficar um pouco mais complexo, mas vale a pena. :D

São muitos detalhes que eu não conseguiria explicar aqui de maneira breve, mas vou te dar o caminho das pedras: pesquise por API Rest com PHP e ajax.

Answer (score 1):

O php foi criado para ser integrado com o html, mas hoje em dia quanto menos contato direto os dois tiverem vai ser melhor, por isso pense no padrão MVC usando um sistema de templates, como o twig por exemplo.

Sei que você está aprendendo ainda, mas esse seria o melhor caminho para você, na minha humilde opinião.